# Jquery Toggle + extra close button

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

i wrote this little Toggle Script and i want to add an extra "close" button into my open wrapper. So someone can open and close it with a click on "Button" but also close it with a click on "close".

I hope someone can help me. 
Greetings. :)

```
 <div class="ia1">Button</div>
<div class="ib1">
<p>
Text
</p>
<div id="close">close</div>
</div>
```

JQ:

```
function() {
  $(".ia1").toggle(
      function(){ 
    $('.ib1').css("display","block"),
    $('.ib1').animate({ height: $('p')[0].scrollHeight+'px'},200),      
    $('.ia1').html('<div class="icon icon2"></div>Close')
    },
     function(){
    $('.ib1').animate({height:10},200),
    $('.ia1').html('<div class="icon"></div>Open'),
    setTimeout(function(){$('.ib1').css("display","none")},200)
      });
});
```

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: So, hope this explains it a little bit better. http://jsfiddle.net/NHacg/

Comment: F.Y.I. [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine.

```
 $("#close").click(function () {
$(".ia1").trigger("click");
});
```

Trigger() works quite well.